# Can the a backbutton press be detected from a service?

Tags: android

Can the a backbutton press be detected from a service?

As the header says really? I have done a lot of googling but can't find a definitive answer.
Nor a way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

> Can the a backbutton press be detected from a service?

No, sorry. If you have an activity in the foreground, the activity can detect a BACK press. If you do not have an activity in the foreground, the BACK button has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: I don't think this is entirely correct. The Service, for example, could execute code that shows a Window using `WindowManager#addView()`, and if that Window gains focus, the `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK` event will be delivered to the root view of the window, I assume? It all depends on which window currently has focus... not the type of component you are using. Of course, 99% of the time your service will not be showing its own windows to the screen (unless you are re-writing Facebook Chatheads), so services in general won't be able to receive back-button click events.

Comment: I am doing some chathead service demo. How I can add a listener to the window? I try it with `setonkeylistener` on a view but i can't catch de back action... :s

Answer (score 2):

Don't think so. Back button is something managed at activity level, while a service is totally separated from this level.

The only way you have is to communicate a back pression from your activity to your service. But, you need that your activity is in foreground.

Answer (score 0):

If through your service your are adding view or something then you can use EditText box to capture back press. Just set its onKeyListerner.
(Hide edittext box behind other view)

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                Log.d("TAG", "onKey() called with: " + "v = [" + v + "], keyCode = [" + keyCode + "], event = [" + event + "]");
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction()== KeyEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    onBackPress();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```