# how to handle hardware back button from a service in android

Tags: java, android, back

I'm writing a client program where I'm running a service in server for communication.
android hardware back button can be controlled through `OnKeyDown` method or `OnBackPressed` Method from an activity.
But how its done from a service ?

Comment: Does [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2000319/4385913) helps you?

Comment: Not Working...@JoanColmenero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to detect hardware "BACK " press from Service.

If you have an activity in the foreground, the activity can detect a BACK press.
In this case, your Activity communicate a BACK Press from your activity to your Service.

> Why it is so?

Service in principle, is an app component developed to perform long running operations in "Background". See the below quotes from Android docs:

> A service does not provide a user interface. For example, a service
>   might play music in the background while the user is in a different
>   app, or it might fetch data over the network without blocking user
>   interaction with an activity

Actions such as "Back" press are user-driven and hence closely tied to User interface which in Android is Activity.

Hence, Android framework offers API Related to handling "Back" press using Activity and not using Services.

Almost all the time your service will not be showing its own windows to the screen. So services won't be able to receive back-button click events.

You may read some Interesting discussion on this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183243/can-the-a-backbutton-press-be-detected-from-a-service).

Comment: Then How to handle that hardware back button... Can you suggest any thing...@AADTechnical

Comment: if you have Activity, you can override `onBackPressed()` to handle "BACK" Press. Capture what you want here and then send it to Service. I mentioned the same in my Answer about this.

Comment: I'm sorry if i've conveyed in a wrong manner, my problem is I've an android box and I'm writing a client remote app to control it, So I don't know which activity is Running in it. That is why I've asked how to control hardware back button.   How to override System `onBackPressed()`  method  @AADTechnical